# How to test a method that does a *lot* of argument processing?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have the following method defined in my app:

```
def self.analyze(params)
  processed_params = params.flat_map do |metric, value|
    Moods::Processors.processors[metric].map { |p| p.process(value) }
  end

  weighted_moods = processed_params.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |memo, pp|
    memo.merge(pp) { |_, left, right| left + right }
  end

  normalized_moods = Moods.pairs.each_with_object({}) do |(pos, neg), memo|
    normalized_weight = weighted_moods[pos] - weighted_moods[neg]
    if normalized_weight > 0.0
      memo[pos] = normalized_weight
    elsif normalized_weight < 0.0
      memo[neg] = normalized_weight.abs
    end
  end

  sorted_moods = normalized_moods.sort_by { |_, v| -v }.map(&:first)

  mood_combinations = sorted_moods.size.downto(1).flat_map do |i|
    sorted_moods.combination(i).to_a
  end
end
```

My main concern is: how do I test this method? The only *approachable* way I see is compute some generic scenarios that roughly go through each case/branch in the code. But this isn't thorough testing.

Another idea is to separate each snippet of code in a private method and unit test it. But private methods shouldn't be tested...

If I want to the everything **thorough**, I would probably end up with some very complicated matrix.

So, which is the desired way to test this method?

Comment: When you say "private methods shouldn't be tested" you mean *directly*. They should, of course, be exercised indirectly.

Comment: Of course, but then the result of testing those private methods indirectly is the same as testing the above method directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing code like this sometimes a regular unit test is not really enough to exercise all the behaviours necessary to ensure it's working correctly.

There's some design problems here, this method does a lot of work and inspecting the results of the intermediate operations is not practical. If you could break out some of those operations as public methods that can be tested individually that would help.

How I usually tackle things like this is by creating a directory in `test/` where there are dozens of "scenario" files. A serialization format like JSON or YAML is used to define a data structure, and then you have a unit test that spins through all of these and verifies that they work correctly.

Here's how one might be structured:

```
given:
  a: 1
  b: 2
expect:
  3
```

Where say you had a very simple function `f(a,b)` and you want to ensure that the result of it is `a + b`. You'll want to explore edge cases, conditions where the behaviour changes.

Comment: I've thought about extracting methods, but declaring them as public doesn't help, I don't want to expose them. Regarding the scenario, I also had this in mind; but how can I be _almost_ sure that I test most cases properly? It's just a bunch of scenarios which will be hard to maintain if the specs change.

Comment: That's the nature of tests. If the specs change, the tests change. Remember, tests minimize defects, but do not ever eliminate them entirely.

Comment: @AndreiHorak private methods can be a code smell, especially when they make testing difficult. Moving them into other classes can help: http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/write-private-functions-not-private-methods

Comment: @zetetic I agree it can help, but in my example I don't see what I can extract. My method just receives an input and processes it a lot.

Comment: That's where structuring this differently might pay dividends. You could create a class that handles transforming this data and have public methods for examining the intermediate products, via `attr_accessor`, or have public methods that produce the intermediate products. Walling off things as `private` is sometimes a good thing, it helps focus people on the methods they're intended to use, but other times it obscures from testing things that are critical to get right. Find the right balance here. What's the harm in having public methods that you shouldn't use, but just do transformations?

Comment: I've written my method this way because there is no reason whatsoever to see or manipulate intermediate steps in the whole process. You may be indeed right that by having separate, public methods it would be easier to test, but should I write code with the easiness of testing as my primary goal?

Comment: If you're writing code that can't be tested, you've got problems. If you're thinking about testing when writing code, you might have an easier time of verifying it works. Some philosophies encourage writing the tests first so you never forget to do it, and in this case the code must be highly testable. I'd encourage you to think about it that way. Black-box code is extremely annoying to work with as it's often unclear why a minor mistake is occurring, there's no way of isolating what component malfunctioned. You need to check the whole thing in the event of a failure.

Comment: I understand. I will follow your advice then and see where I get.

Comment: I've ended up separating methods as you said, but kept them private, so as to keep some of the benefits of both approaches. Thank you!